# Input image with :hover text and opacity

Tags: css

How can I make that the hover option allows me to see the image with opacity and the p tag inside not affected by opacity style? Please note that the img is inside an input tag and when I click it a bootsrap modal  will appear with input form

```css
 .img_wrap:hover 
 #updateImg{ opacity: 0.7; }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="img_wrap">
     <input type='image' id='updateImg' src='http://placehold.it/350x150'>
       </input>
       <span></span><p class="imgText">Click here to change your image</p>
     </div>
```

Comment: Do you want the image to appear on hover?

Comment: No, the image have to stay on the background with opacity and on the top have to appear a text "Click here to change your image"

Comment: is this what you want 
     .img_wrap:hover #updateImg{
      opacity: 0.7;
     }

Comment: Yes but at the same time I need the text over the image

Comment: Should the text only appear when the image is hovered over?

Comment: Yes I need it. When the cursor is over the image

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle each children's opacity separately. Also, if you want them overlapped, you need one of them (the text in my example, positioned `absolute` and the parent `relative`).

I'm guessing the following example does what you want to achieve? If not, please state your request clearer.

```css
.img_wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img_wrap input[type="image"]{
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1)
}
.img_wrap:hover input[type="image"] {
  opacity: .3;
}
.img_wrap .imgText {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1)
}
.img_wrap:hover .imgText {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_wrap">
  <input type='image' id='updateImg' src='http://placehold.it/350x150' />
  <div class="imgText">Click here to change your image</div>
</div>
```

**Notes:**

- `<input>` is a self-closing tag, so `<input></input>` is invalid.
- `<input type="image">` is supposed to be used instead of a (submit) button. It's a shortcut for a button with a background image, that resizes itself to the image ratio. If you want to submit an image to the server using an `<input>`, you probably want to use `<input type="file" />`

Comment: @Janus :) Yep, I meant input. (I actually wrote it correctly 3 words further down the line). Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Thanks but now the input doesn't work. The bootstrap modal doesn't apper

Comment: @PaoloPorcellato Realized it just a few moments ago and updated my code prior to your comment. You need to let the `pointer-events` pass through the `.imgText` using `pointer-events: none;` See updated answer. Alternatively, you could just place the `.imgText` before the `<input>` in your markup and the `<input>` would be the one catching the clicks, being last in DOM (painted over previous siblings).

Answer (score 1):

here is what you want

```
.img_wrap{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.img_wrap:hover #updateImg{
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: relative;
}
.img_wrap:hover .imgText{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
}
```